# Customization of SP OOTB Picture Slide Show Display

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, customization, content-srch-slider

I am working with SP Online and have SA privileges.

I am using the SP OOTB Picture Slideshow under 'Media and Content' on a single column page. I do not have SP Designer or JQuery as my company won't allow the download of any programs.

The Display is really BLAH with the Title/Description to the right with very basic formatting and very limited width.

What I would like to do is display the Title/Description on the image with a black semi transparent background, bold titling, and new font type.

Can anyone assist with this? I have a pretty good understanding of script/content editor but just in case - breaking down in "Barney Style" is good too.

I appreciate you all!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a browser with  decent developer tools, it should be pretty simple. Follow the steps in this video, once you have identified the proper tags and classes, https://youtu.be/dsha7YVod-Y